# flask doesn't register an exception

Tags: python, exception, flask

here is my exception class 
    DB_ERROR_REMOVE = 203

```
CLOUD_ERROR = 300

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code, message, recommendation):
        self.code = code
        self.message = message
        self.recommendation = recommendation
        Exception.__init__(self)
```

here is the flask init code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.errorhandler(MyError)
def my_exception_handler(error):
    return "!!!!"  + repr(error) + repr(traceback.format_exc())
```

and I'm raising my error like so:

```
raise MyError(1,"bla","foo")
```

doesn't catch it. 
if I do the same with Exception, it indeed catches it:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def my_exception_handler(error):
    return "!!!!"  + repr(error) + repr(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that I was using `add_resource` to define routes in my app

once I defined them using the `@app.route`
the Exception

```
@app.route('/<string:productName>/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get(productName, examUniq): 
    raise MyError(111, "message", "test")

@app.errorhandler(MyError)
def my_exception_handler(error):
    return "!!!!"  + repr(error) + repr(traceback.format_exc())
```

the error was caught.